# When publishing the first version of a plugin into the aragonOSx protocol, what should I put in the parameters?

Tags: solidity, factory, framework, repositories

- What should I set as the `maintainer`?
- What should I set as the `_releaseMetadata`?
- What should I set as the `_buildMetadata`?

[image: createPluginRepoWithFristVersion function within the PluginRepoFactory contract]

Answer (score 0):

- The `maintainer` address is your address as a maintainer. It is the address of the only one able to publish new versions of that plugin.
- For now, the `_releaseMetadata` and the `_buildMetada` attributes can remain empty for now. They are in place for future compatibility, since we don't want to come back and do breaking ABI changes in the future.

For context, the `_releaseMetadata` will be an IPFS CID (`"ipfs://<cid>"`) pointing to a JSON file, but it is not used right now.